Unable to run Jenkins Pipeline
i am running jenkins inside the docker container. Now all i want is that inside docker container it should run the terraform commands by using the docker terraform image and then once the task is completed by terraform container then the terraform container should exit.
pipeline
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            agent {
                docker {
                    image 'hashicorp/terraform:1.3.7'
                    
                }
            }
            steps {
                sh './terraform init'
                git branch: 'main', url: 'https://github.com/sharatbhaskar1988/terraformtest.git'
                
            }
        }
    }
}

Error:
    Started by user sharat
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in /var/jenkins_home/workspace/terraform
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Build)
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in /var/jenkins_home/workspace/terraform@2
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] isUnix
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
+ docker inspect -f . hashicorp/terraform:1.3.7
.
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] withDockerContainer
Jenkins seems to be running inside container 10909deec57556592bae5ae088e4d4f2e653498944f647e1c96ae1ee263162ae
but /var/jenkins_home/workspace/terraform@2 could not be found among []
but /var/jenkins_home/workspace/terraform@2@tmp could not be found among []
$ docker run -t -d -u 0:0 -v /var/jenkins_home/workspace:/var/jenkins_home/workspace -w /var/jenkins_home/workspace/terraform@2 -v /var/jenkins_home/workspace/terraform@2:/var/jenkins_home/workspace/terraform@2:rw,z -v /var/jenkins_home/workspace/terraform@2@tmp:/var/jenkins_home/workspace/terraform@2@tmp:rw,z -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** hashicorp/terraform:1.3.7 cat
$ docker top 988d64e60b16cf8f9491fe971b68f46e1ee0221e62379f80198fa74a76247eb7 -eo pid,comm
[Pipeline] // withDockerContainer
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Also:   org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.actions.ErrorAction$ErrorId: 912882de-5460-4b49-b3dc-9b0a67aa71bb
java.io.IOException: Failed to run top '988d64e60b16cf8f9491fe971b68f46e1ee0221e62379f80198fa74a76247eb7'. Error: Error response from daemon: Container 988d64e60b16cf8f9491fe971b68f46e1ee0221e62379f80198fa74a76247eb7 is not running

